# Yii caching share caching between console app and web app?

Tags: caching, yii, redis

I am creating caching for my app using console app.
But i unable share that cache for my web app.
(in my redis database its showing created from console)
any idea how can i share cache created from console to my web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frontend configuration file:

```
'cache' => array(
    'class'     => 'system.caching.' . (!MW_DEBUG ? 'CFileCache' : 'CDummyCache'),
    'keyPrefix' => md5('frontend.' . MW_VERSION . Yii::getPathOfAlias('frontend')),
),
```

Console configuration file:

```
'cache' => array(
  'class'     => 'system.caching.' . (!MW_DEBUG ? 'CFileCache' : 'CDummyCache'),
  'keyPrefix' => md5('console.' . MW_VERSION . Yii::getPathOfAlias('backend')),
),
```

[reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593508/single-cache-frontend-and-backend)

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same issue which was resolved by keeping same setting for backend and frontend both apps.

```
'cache'=> array(
    'class' => 'CRedisCache',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
    'hashKey' => false,
    'keyPrefix' => '',
);
```

set keyPrefix to empty and hashKey to false,

if you use default setting for keyPrefix and hashKey CRedisCache will create different keys for same value provided from set command
eg.

```
 Yii::app()->cache->set('foo', 'bar'); frontend server 
will create key in redis something like "0327f5f7378e9056c775ab69aa206322"

  Yii::app()->cache->set('foo', 'bar'); backend server 
ll create key in redis something like "d2c81df2db2285435c1975b5cb5c5b66"
```

CRedisCache creates unique key by using combination of hashKey and keyPrefix for every requested server.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to actually set the hashKey to false (in fact you should not). Just ensuring the keyPrefix to be the same on both console & web application should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to set the same keyPrefix for both applications

```php
'cache' => [
    'class'     => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    'keyPrefix' => 'common'
],
```

Tested with Yii2 basic template.