# Single cache frontend and backend

Tags: php, caching, yii, redis

I want to use tagging cache in Yii.

But it turns out that for the frontend using its cache for its backend. When I do change the model in the backend, the front of the cache is not cleared. There are any solutions for this?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set distinct cache prefix for frontend and backend in their respective configuration files.

I am still using 1.1.x branch, but for 2.x branch should be the same thing.

Frontend configuration file:

```
'cache' => array(
        'class'     => 'system.caching.' . (!MW_DEBUG ? 'CFileCache' : 'CDummyCache'),
        'keyPrefix' => md5('frontend.' . MW_VERSION . Yii::getPathOfAlias('frontend')),
 ),
```

Backend configuration file:

```
'cache' => array(
        'class'     => 'system.caching.' . (!MW_DEBUG ? 'CFileCache' : 'CDummyCache'),
        'keyPrefix' => md5('backend.' . MW_VERSION . Yii::getPathOfAlias('backend')),
    ),
```

Comment: @Twisted1919 i just would like to add something here, if I dont provide key prefix, will it be a cause for DB locking for sqlite cache DB ??

Answer (score 0):

In my case, at runtime of caching service in DI, for FileCache, setting another cachePath also works fine.

```
        //in backend
        $cache = \Yii::$app->cache;
        if ($cache instanceof FileCache) {
            $cache->cachePath = \Yii::getAlias('@frontend/runtime/cache');
            $cache->set('my_cache_prefix', $myData);
        }
        //This way I have overridden expired cache in frontend
```